# SwiftUI get selected range from TextEditor

Tags: ios, swiftui

I would like to get the selected text range from a TextEditor in SwiftUI.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Urkman

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you figure it out?